# Problema em definir Foreign key

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou aprender agora base de dados. Não estou a entender o porque de não estar a deixar eu definir team_id como foreign key.

Comment: Daina, pelo que li na documentação, me parece que sua tabela Team não tem chave primaria definida. O que me parece estranho, que pleo print do seu modelo ER, a sua tabela Team, não tem uma coluna Team_ID e sim uma coluna Id.

Comment: Pablo obrigado era realmente isso, mas eu nao estava conseguindo definir team_id como FK da tabela Attendance e Person, estava dando o erro que mostro na foto, Mas consegui definir team_id na tabela LEAGUE como primary e foreign será por na tabela LEAGUE ja estava como primary?

Comment: Muito provavelmente sim, no momento q vc definiu q a ligação entre a tabela League e Team, e a chave primária está na tabela League, vc criou uma relação de 1 para N entre League e Team, mas no momento q vc definir a PK em Team, vc terá uma relação de 1 para 1 entre as tabelas League e Team. Só tem q cuidar qual das duas q terá a chave primária na hora de definir a FK. Por exemplo se vc definir q a Referencing Column, for o Id da tabela Team, isso significa que o registro terá que existir primeiro na tabela Team, para depois você inserir na tabela League. Se eu estiver erroado, me corrijam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que lhe falta é definir a coluna Id na sua tabela Team como chave primária.

Para adicionar uma chave primaria em uma tabela, você pode usar o comando `ALTER TABLE`.

Sua `syntax` é:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

Ou pelo SQL Developer, clique com o direito do mouse na tabela desejada e selcione o menu *Edit*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione o item *Primary Key*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione qual é a sua chave primária
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por último clique no OK.

---

Referências:

<sub>[Oracle / PLSQL: Primary Keys](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php). Disponível em: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php.
 Acesso em: 25 Nov. 2017.</sub>

<sub>[Getting Started with Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/257055.htm). Disponível em: http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/257055.htm. Acesso em: 25 Nov. 2017.</sub>

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/142834)

Comment: Acho que agora melhorou.